# 'findOneAndUpdate()' does not update the existing data in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using MEAN Stack with Angular 6. There if the user previously has added data into the db that data should be updated. For that I used `findOneAndUpdate()` method. **But without updating the existing data it posts another data set into the db.**

This is my post route. This 'userName' comes from a different schema.

```js
router.post('/save', function(req, res) {
  var mod = new rdaColor(req.body);

  rdaColor.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      userName: req.body.userName,
      colorMovementBox: req.body.colorMovementBox
    },
    req.body,
    { upsert: true, new: true },
    function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send(mod);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

This is schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    // Schema for rda color panel
    var rdaColorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        userName: {
            type: String
        },
        colorMovementBox: {
            type: String,
        },

    });


module.exports = mongoose.model('rdaColor', rdaColorSchema);
```

This is the output for the following console.log.

```
console.log("mod"+mod+" "+(req.body));
```

output

```
mod{ _id: 5bbd68344619a612b07a688e,
  userName: 'abc@yahoo.com',
  colorMovementBox: 'rgb(49,64,116)',
  } [object Object]
```

How can I make it only to update the data.

Comment: Sorry I am new to MEAN Stack. How can I remove that part?

Comment: What is the content of `req.body`? Can you add to the question a console.log of it

Comment: I added the schema

Comment: @Akrion updated the question with the output of the console.log

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate()` does a partial update operation with a specifically designed update document. What you need is `findOneAndReplace()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try.

Comment: You also have `upsert:true` so make sure that you have a record with `'abc@yahoo.com'` username and `'rgb(49,64,116)'`colorMovementBox.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query.

> This will update if data exists with `Id` and create new if not exists.
>
> If you remove `upsert: true` then it does not create a new record if not exists.

```
rdaColor.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "yourId" },
  {
    $set: {
      userName: req.body.userName,
      colorMovementBox: req.body.colorMovementBox
    }
  },
  { upsert: true, new: true },
  function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }
    console.log(doc);
  }
);
```

Comment: Your description for the answer is correct. As far as I understood, here when I add a new value it checks for both userName and the 'movementBox'. Then it becomes a new object. That is why it posts again. When I check only the constant one(userName) and remove the other one in post route it works as expected. Thanks for your description.